# Give the value of $a$ such that this ODE has a unique solution.

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

> Let $$L y = y''(x) + a \delta(x-1) y(x) = f(x)$$ subject to $y(0)=c_1$, $y(\pi)=c_2$. Let $c_i$ be just constants and $f(x)$ sufficiently smooth. This system has a unique solution except at a value of $a$ which you should specify.

---

I am assuming this has something to do with Fredholm Alternative Theorem, which partially states the system has a unique solution if and only if the problem, $Ly=0$, subject to homogeneous version of the boundary conditions of the above system, only has the trivial solution.

Now, solving $Ly=0$ appears to be quite problematic to me. When I considered when $x\not =1$, $y$ is just identically zero. Then I have no idea how to proceed, I think the delta function here really makes me feel uncomfortable. Any idea on how to proceed? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By the sifting property, $δ(x−1)y(x)=δ(x−1)y(1)$. Now you just integrate twice, if $\Phi''=f$, you get
$$
y(x)=\Phi(x)-\frac{a}{2}y(1)|x-1|+Cx+D
$$
The boundary conditions read
\begin{align}
y(1)&=\Phi(1)+C+D\\
c_1=y(0)&=\Phi(0)-\frac{a}2y(1)+D\\
c_2=y(\pi)&=\Phi(\pi)-\frac{a(\pi-1)}{2}y(1)+C\pi+D\\
\end{align}
Now you would have to check if the linear system in $C,D$ by the last two equation, after inserting the first, can become singular.

---

Or as a $3\times 3$ system in $C,D,y(1)$ with the system matrix
$$
\begin{bmatrix}
1&1&-1\\
0&1&-\frac a2\\
\pi&1&-\frac{a(\pi-1)}2
\end{bmatrix}
$$
Now the determinant of this is linear in $a$ so that there will certainly be one value where it is zero.

Comment: +1 Lutz Can you elaborate for the integration of the delta function ? Thanks in advance. I know how to do this DE  with Laplace Transform.

Comment: The Dirac delta is the derivative of a unit jump or the second derivative of a piecewise linear continuous function where the derivative has a jump of one. For $\delta(x-1)$ the function $\frac12|x-1|$ fits this bill, as does $\max(1,x)$, $-\min(1,x)$ etc.

Comment: Thanks for these informations.